# Cannot locate /usr/share/examples/svr4 on NetBSD 9.2 32-bit

Tags: sparc, netbsd, binary-emulation

I'm attempting to setup a (32-bit) NetBSD 9.2 virtual machine with QEMU so that I can run SPARC binaries on it, specifically those that were compiled on Solaris machines (currently I've compiled a short C program on Solaris 8 and am trying to run it on NetBSD). During this endeavor, one website I was directed to is [here](https://man.netbsd.org/NetBSD-6.0/compat_svr4.8). Specifically, step #4 of that page references a `/usr/share/examples/emul/svr4` directory, which I cannot locate on my NetBSD instance. The only subdirectory within the `.../emul` directory is `linux`.

I largely followed the steps outlined [here](https://www.netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/chap-exinst.html) to install NetBSD.

I'm curious as to what specific packages/configuration settings are required in order to get the `.../emul/svr4` directory to appear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COMPAT_SVR4 was [removed](https://mail-index.netbsd.org/source-changes/2018/12/19/msg101565.html) (for various reasons, security and maintenance being the prominent ones) prior to the NetBSD 9 release branch. The manual page you've referenced is actually that of NetBSD 6.0, and is not part of your 9.2 installation.

Thus in order to get started you might install NetBSD 8.2 or even a daily snapshot of the netbsd-8 branch, which is still being maintained.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that; thank you for the information, in any case! I will give NetBSD 8.2 a shot, then.